# How to fetch PublishedPort from inspect

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I'm trying to fecth the `PublishedPort` from my docker service.

I think I'm close to fetch it. Here is the data :

```
[
    {
        "ID": "a51ijaddvaf1paeh1dn5p1k3",
        "Version": {
            "Index": 240
        },
        "CreatedAt": "2020-08-24T14:41:37.217303114Z",
        "UpdatedAt": "2020-08-24T14:41:37.22448218Z",
        "Spec": {
            "Name": "My_app",
            "Labels": {},
            "TaskTemplate": {
                "ContainerSpec": {
                    "Image": "tuxgasy/dolibarr:latest@sha256:a2d6c8e1ed7127c5cb74da2faj41a7a14zger77d4",
                    "Env": [
                        "DOLI_DB_HOST=HOST",
                    ],
                    "Init": false,
                    "Mounts": [
                        {
                            "Type": "volume",
                            "Source": "nfsvolume",
                            "Target": "/FOLDER",
                            "VolumeOptions": {
                                "DriverConfig": {
                                    "Name": "local",
                                    "Options": {
                                        "device": ":/FOLDER",
                                        "o": "addr=192.168.0.1",
                                        "type": "nfs"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "Type": "volume",
                            "Source": "nfsvolume",
                            "Target": "/FOLDER2",
                            "VolumeOptions": {
                                "DriverConfig": {
                                    "Name": "local",
                                    "Options": {
                                        "device": ":/FOLDER2",
                                        "o": "addr=192.168.0.1",
                                        "type": "nfs"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "StopGracePeriod": 10000000000,
                    "DNSConfig": {},
                    "Isolation": "default"
                },
                "Resources": {
                    "Limits": {},
                    "Reservations": {}
                },
                "RestartPolicy": {
                    "Condition": "any",
                    "Delay": 5000000000,
                    "MaxAttempts": 0
                },
                "Placement": {
                    "Platforms": [
                        {
                            "Architecture": "amd64",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "ForceUpdate": 0,
                "Runtime": "container"
            },
            "Mode": {
                "Replicated": {
                    "Replicas": 2
                }
            },
            "UpdateConfig": {
                "Parallelism": 1,
                "FailureAction": "pause",
                "Monitor": 5000000000,
                "MaxFailureRatio": 0,
                "Order": "stop-first"
            },
            "RollbackConfig": {
                "Parallelism": 1,
                "FailureAction": "pause",
                "Monitor": 5000000000,
                "MaxFailureRatio": 0,
                "Order": "stop-first"
            },
            "EndpointSpec": {
                "Mode": "vip",
                "Ports": [
                    {
                        "Protocol": "tcp",
                        "TargetPort": 80,
                        "PublishMode": "ingress"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "Endpoint": {
            "Spec": {
                "Mode": "vip",
                "Ports": [
                    {
                        "Protocol": "tcp",
                        "TargetPort": 80,
                        "PublishMode": "ingress"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Ports": [
                {
                    "Protocol": "tcp",
                    "TargetPort": 80,
                    "PublishedPort": 30001,
                    "PublishMode": "ingress"
                }
            ],
            "VirtualIPs": [
                {
                    "NetworkID": "s8hkvdfzer42onr1ez4",
                    "Addr": "10.0.0.30/24"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

I'm trying to fetch `PublishedPort`.

I tried the following:

```
docker service inspect -f '{{with index .Spec.EndpointSpec.Ports 0}}{{.PublishedPort}}{{end}}' My_app
docker service inspect -f '{{with index .Spec.Endpoint.Spec.Ports 0}}{{.PublishedPort}}{{end}}' My_app
docker service inspect -f '{{.Spec.EndpointSpec.Ports 0}}{{.PublishedPort}}{{end}}' My_app
docker service inspect -f '{{with index .Spec.EndpointPorts 0}}{{.PublishedPort}}{{end}}' My_app
docker service inspect -f '{{with index .Spec.Endpoint.Ports 0}}{{.PublishedPort}}{{end}}' My_app
docker service inspect --format '{{json .Endpoint.Ports.PublishedPort}}' My_app
docker service inspect -f '{{with index .EndpointSpec.Ports 0}}{{.PublishedPort}}{{end}}' My_app
docker service inspect -f '{{with index .Spec.EndpointSpec.Ports 0}}{{.PublishedPort}}{{end}}' My_app
docker service inspect -f '{{with index .EndpointSpec.Ports 0}}{{.PublishedPort}}{{end}}' My_app
docker service inspect --format '{{json .Endpoint.Ports 0}}{{.PublishedPort}}' My_app
docker service inspect --format '{{json .Endpoint.Ports}}{{.PublishedPort}}' My_app
```